# WPF: Calculating window size based on content

Tags: wpf, window, sizetocontent

I need to fit the window's width and height to its content. I'm aware of existance of SizeToClient property of Window, however, if one chooses WidthAndHeight as the value of SizeToClient, window events are fired in invalid way, such that several components raise an exception during Loaded event: "Hwnd of zero is not valid" (for example GlassWindow's SetAeroGlassTransparency from Windows API CodePack).

Is there a workaround? I may calculate the window size manually, but I do not know, how to retrieve the window's chrome sizes (in other words, the *real* window's content margin sizes).

[Details of WPF bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552750/order-of-window-startup-events-changes-when-sizetocontent-widthandheight?wa=wsignin1.0)

Best regards -- Spook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`SystemParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) to determine the size of the chrome. For example, [`SystemParameters.CaptionHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.systemparameters.captionheight.aspx).

Comment: Ok, that shall allow me calculate the difference between non-client and client area manually when resizing contents and it shall be sufficient workaround for the WPF bug. I hope, that I won't encounter more such annoying bugs... Thanks for help!